# Linux : rebooting on distro from another installed one

Tags: linux, ubuntu, arch-linux, dual-boot

## Problem

On a "Linux only" computer (no Windows at all), I tend to like to have two distributions :

- a "main" distribution, Manjaro, which I use for mostly everything, because I like it and I'm used to it.
- a "gaming" distribution, Ubuntu, which I use only when game installation is supported on Ubuntu and is not supported/a pain on Manjaro.

As I don't boot that often on Ubuntu, I would love to be able to boot as fast as if I was not in dual boot setup (thus skipping bootloader menu) and only had Manjaro installed, but to still be able to reboot into Ubuntu from a booted Manjaro.

## What I'm looking for

I look for any solution which would enable me to boot really fast into Manjaro but still allowing me to use Ubuntu when I want to.

I want to avoid (but it's ok if there is no other solution) ; 
complicated scripting or system tweaking (no problem for small tweaks/scripts) as well as solutions lowering significantly (around 15% speed loss or more) performances of either main or gaming distros.

Comment: "... solutions lowering significantly performances of either main or gaming distros" is way too broad.

Comment: @Panki wow you are right, i'll make it more precise

Comment: Have you tried setting `GRUB_TIMEOUT=0` and pressing SHIFT (BIOS) or ESC (UEFI) during boot to access grub menu if necessary? Or is it a must to have it without interaction?

Comment: Which bootloader are you using?  If it's Grub, you can have it [switch to a different entry only for the next boot](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/legacy/Booting-once_002donly.html).

Comment: @Fiximan this was one of the solutions I wanted to avoid, because I am a bit "head in the cloud" and I tend to forget to do the interactions. For my current computer I didn't used it because boot/reboot was quite slow, but maybe on my next PC I'll use it if boot/reboot is fast enough for me to not get distracted  x)

Comment: @JigglyNaga O.o nice solution, I definitely wasn't aware of that existing. I'll dig a bit more into it to see if I can make it clearer (more verbose) or if it exists an utility wrapping this to make it clearer. But it feels nice and light indeed.

Comment: @FelixBertoni Well, ssd prices are low enough to allow switching at a reasonable cost (and keep the old drive as data storage). Even for "head in cloud"-people ;)

Comment: @Fiximan Well, I know that SSD are fast since I have one, but my question was not about hardware. What takes most of the time for my computer to boot is bootloader timer (the one to allow me to choose OS, and which i want to get rid off) right now. So of course setting time to 0 and pressing button can be a solution, but if I have a way to also reboot from one os into another, that would be better. (JigglyNaga did provide it tho)